# Information from plot of sorted values of a vector

Tags: distributions, data-visualization

Can we get any meaningful information (especially regarding its distribution) from a simple plot of sorted values of a vector? For example, what would following plot convey:

```
plot(sort(xx))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a plot of the inverse cumulative distribution function of whatever distribution the data is sampled from.

For example:

```
x <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
xs <- sort(x)

# Your plot
plot(1:100/100, xs)
```

[image]

```
# The inverse of your plot
plot(xs, 1:100/100)
# The cdf of the distribution
lines(seq(-3, 3, by=.1), pnorm(seq(-3, 3, by=.1)))
```

[image]

To see this, you can argue that, for $(x,y)$ the points in your plot:

$$\# \{ (x,y) \mid a < y < b \} \approx Pr(a < y < b) $$

where the probability is with respect to whatever distribution $y$ is sampled from.  So for $f$ a function approximating your plot:

$$ f^{-1}(b) \approx \# \{ (x,y) \mid y < b \} \approx Pr(y < b) $$

Comment: So why this graph is not used more often to check for distribution. It is very simple to plot. In R:  plot(sort(x))

Comment: Check out the source code to `qqplot`.

Comment: (+1). To address the question in your comment, rnso, this plot is usually a poor choice to check distributions except when comparing to a uniform distribution. The underlying principle is that people can easily and automatically detect deviations from linearity but cannot as reliably detect deviations from other reference curves. This principle leads to favoring qq plots and probability plots as better graphical choices for evaluating empirical distributions.

Comment: I agree with that. My only point was that plotting this curve is easy and understandable (plot of sorted variable). A normal distribution will show rapid rises at beginning and at end but slower rise in the middle part. QQplot is a better plot, being linear hence easy to compare, but less understandable as to how the points got into one line.

Comment: Sorry @mso, I was a little glib with my `qqplot` comment.  If you check out the source for that function, the authors do something very similar to what you're up to here.

Answer (score 1):

Matthew's answer is sufficient, but I thought somebody should answer the actual question(s) as asked:

> What would following plot convey?

### Percentile values:

This graph is the graph of percentiles; the median is always the center of the horizontal axis.

If the horizontal axis is normalized over the total number of samples, 0-1 or 1-100, the percentiles can be directly read.

### Distribution possibilities:

> especially regarding its distribution

Yes, every perfect distribution has a unique shape on this plot.

Unfortunately, no randomly sampled variable is perfect.

For example, if the values only included -.9 to 1 the data distribution could be classified as either skewed uniform or normal, given the near linearity over that range.

**Plot the various distributions and skews to get a feel for the overall shape and feel of each one.**

The information can then be extended to bi-modal and multi-modal data.

---

The overall shape of the OP's given curve indicates a left skewed normal distribution.

### Slopes and curvature:

When the points are connected, the resulting graph can be analyzed as a monotonically increasing line segments, with continuous slope values.

Slopes(first derivative) can be calculated either discretely by subtracting consecutive values, or applying a spline calculation to approximate the slope of multiple consecutive values(allows interpolations if the "time" axis is not consistent). Repeat for 2nd derivative on same plot.

The longest flat value indicates the mode.

A stepped look indicates discrete values or fixed A/D resolution.

Long straight lines are uniform distributions skewed by the slope amount away from 1.

Non-uniform curvature about horizontal lines indicates multi-modal distributions.

---

The 2nd derivative of your plot shows the left side of the data grows slower than the right, indicating a left skew. (Hard to see from your data plot, larger bend length or cupping on the left side.)

### Outliers:

Long near vertical non-symmetric heads or tails indicate outliers in the data.

---

From your graph, values(y-axis) below ~-2 or above ~1.5 are outliers and should be removed.

---

### Description of the visualization:

This graph is not good for quantitative values other than percentiles, and obvious modes, but it does show qualitatively: discreteness, distribution, modality, skew and outlier presence in a single graph.

### Conclusion:

For non-time series numeric data, this plot, along with its 1st and 2nd derivatives and the mean horizontal line, is the second plot, after the data itself, that I run, since it is the most versatile visualization when read correctly.

**Since, its data is not easily interpreted(slopes and curvature), its usefulness to most end users is limited, and as such should not be distributed as a final graph.**

To the trained eye, the information given is very useful and has very little computational overhead compared to convolution.

Any conclusions found are then verified either numerically or via other plots.

Comment: Very informative answer! Welcome to CrossValidated.